# Can i apple remote desktop to a windows 10 machine?

Tags: apple-remote-desktop

Can i use apple remote desktop to control a windows 10 machine on the same LAN ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

While I do not know, if Apple Remote Desktop can be used to control a Windows 10 machine on the same LAN, I can suggest you use the following application instead.

Microsoft provides the "Microsoft Remote Desktop 10" application, which can be used to control a Windows 10 machine on the same LAN (or a remote LAN). The "Microsoft Remote Desktop 10" application can be downloaded for free from the Mac App Store. I should note that not all versions of Windows can be accessed remotely using "Microsoft Remote Desktop 10". For example, the Home versions of Windows will not work with this software.

BTW, many modern PCs are "Wake on LAN" (WOL) capable. If the remote PC is capable of this feature, then you do not have to leave the remote PC on all the time. You can allow the PC to enter hybrid or regular sleep mode, then send a packet over the internet to wake the machine. A Terminal application command for doing this is called `wolcmd`. This command can be downloaded for **free** from the website: [Wake On Lan for Apple Mac OS X 10.6+](https://www.depicus.com/wake-on-lan/wake-on-lan-for-apple-mac). I setup a service, so I can issue this command from the menu bar.

Comment: I don't have any Home machines here to test, but it will connect to Win 7 Pro.

Comment: Upvoted because of the solution but to also answer the question, the answer is "No, you can't." :P

Comment: While this answer is useful, I don't think that answering-question-by-question is the preferred way on SE. From this answer I can only guess that the actual answer to OP's question is "No, [to the best of my knowledge], it's not possible. But I know another solution which might solve your problem...".

If you're actually interested why they'd might want to use app X instead of app Y, there are many reasons, a (silly or not) company policy is just one off the top of my head.

Comment: You have a point. I edited my question. IMO saying "No, [to the best of my knowledge], it's not possible." is just a long way of saying "I do not know".